# Render Azure Blob content in android WebView

Tags: android, azure, webview, azure-blob-storage

I have an HTML file that is stored in Azure Blob, and I am trying to render it in WebView element in my android app. I have stored my file with the extension html - and could see the file's type as text/html in the portal, and in my app I am fetching the blob's url and passing it to the `webView.loadURL(<blob's url>)`. But I get the error message `"Resource not found"` in the emulator.

Is rendering a blob content in `webView` even a supported operation, or I should only resort to read the content from the blob using `blob.OpenInputStream()` and display it?

Comment: Can you please check the ACL of the container in which the blob resides? It should not be `Private`.

Comment: What if I want it to be private, I don't need that blob to be accessible publicly. That's why I am giving my storage key in the connection string. Or have I understood the ACL funda wrongly?

Comment: So you understood ACL "funda" correctly :). In this case what you have to do is create a shared access signature with at least read permission, and use that SAS URL instead of blob URL.

Comment: That worked like a charm. Thank you very much @GauravMantri ! Got to learn about the SAS today! Can you actually add this as the answer so that I shall accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wish to display the contents of a blob by specifying just its URL, there are two ways you can go about it:

1. **Change Container ACL**: You would need to change the ACL of blob container holding the blob to either `Blob` or `Container`. This way the blob can be accessed anonymously using its URL.
2. **Use Shared Access Signature**: If you want to keep the ACL of the container as `Private`, then other option for you would be to use a `Shared Access Signature (SAS)`. A SAS gives time-limited permissions on a storage resource (Blob, Table, Queue, File etc.). In your case, you would need to create a SAS with at least `Read` permission. Once you get the SAS, you just need to append it to your blob URL and you should be able to access the blob from a private container. Please see this link for more details regarding SAS: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/storage-dotnet-shared-access-signature-part-1/.